# How to populate a ViewFlipper child View with a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, viewflipper

I am trying to set up a ViewFlipper that changes a SlidingDrawers content each time a button is pressed. So far every view I set up worked fine, but now I am trying to create a ListView (including single_choice_mode) within a child view of the ViewFlipper, but my attempt only let to a NullPointerException. As I only discovered ViewFlipper today, I am not yet familiar with it and may not have understood it completely...if someone could give me a hand and help me find out what I have done wrong, that would be great.

Thank you in advance.

---

Here is what I have done:

The code for the onClick event of the ImageButtons:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == btnExposure) {

        mFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0);

    } else if (v == btnProperties) {
        mFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
    } else if (v == btnSpecialEffects) {
        mFlipper.setDisplayedChild(2);
        String[] specialEffects = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.special_effects_array);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, R.layout.specialeffectsview, specialEffects));
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }

}
```

The XML code of the ViewFlipper within my main xml file:

```
<ViewFlipper
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/flipper"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_exposure">
   <include android:id="@+id/view_exposure" layout="@layout/exposureview" />
   <include android:id="@+id/view_properties" layout="@layout/propertiesview" />
   <include android:id="@+id/view_special_effects" layout="@layout/specialeffectsview"/>
  </ViewFlipper>
```

The string array within my strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="special_effects_array">
        <item>None</item>
        <item>Greyscale</item>
        <item>Sepia</item>
        <item>Negative</item>
        <item>Solarize</item>
        <item>Polarize</item>
    </string-array>
```

And finally the specialeffectsview.xml (the layout file for the ListView):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/view_special_effects_list"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ListView android:id="@+id/special_effects_list" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been [discussed on the Android Google Groups when you inquired there](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/715850b47f4ca488#), your `NullPointerException` is because your `lv` variable is `null`. You need to make that be not `null`, probably by calling `lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.special_effects_list)` at some point after `setContentView()`.

Comment: I already tried that but as that also didn't work I changed the layout to a simple LinearLayout with a RadioButton Group, not my ideal and final solution, but for now that should do the trick...